# How can I give access of var/www/html to another user using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filezilla

Stack**overflow** community,
I have to add another user in the AWS ec2 user account and also want to give the permission of `/var/www/html` in FileZilla / WinSCP using AWS ec2 user. I have created the user as well as the AWS user policy but it is giving the access of/in FileZilla / WinSCP. Can anyone let me know how can I solve this issue by permitting `/var/www/html` to a specific user?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cannot totally get what are you requiring. But I think this would be a pure Linux permission problem, not an AWS problem.
For changing the permission of a folder in AMZ Linux, you could do it just like that you can assign the permission to a single user or a group in other universal Linux version with ***chmod*** command.

Here are some sample snippets for your reference:

```
sudo chmod [the_new_user_you_created] 755 -R /var/www/html

sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
```

For the best practice, you could find the recommendation for initializing a web server in AWS from this official link:
[To set file permissions for the Apache web server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html)